# undefined reference to `shmctl'

Tags: c, gcc, undefined-reference

i'm trying to compile my programm(it's a server that uses shared memory) and when i try to delete the shared memory(`shmctl()`) inside a signal handler for SIGINT i keep getting

```
undefined reference to `schmctl'
```

i searched around and saw that this usually requires something like

```
 gcc -o server server.c -lrt
```

to compile,but even then i keep getting the same error.
Can anyone help me understand what i should do,and what -lrt or whatever is needed means?

Comment: You misspelled it. **Never** compile without **all warnings**: `-W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wwrite-string` (At least don't come to StackOverflow unless you always use all warnings.)

Comment: thank u for your answer.although i'm not sure i understand how warnings could have prevent this,i should be more careful anyway.if anything,at least it'd save me hours trying to find my mistake in the first place.

Comment: In C you can use functions without declaration (to detrimental effect, as you just learned). With warnings the compiler will alert you to that fact.

Comment: ah,i see.thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-lrt` means you are linking with `librt.a` library. To get rid of your error you should find the library where symbol shmctl is defined and then pass it to `gcc`.

Comment: thanks,i'm accepting this as answer,cause it explains my -lrt question.